# How to run C++ program or any other program using spawn in node.js along with input file from which stdin is to be read

Tags: node.js, spawn

I am trying to run a C++ program from within node.js using the spawn method. The normal way when I try to run just the .exe file by specifying: pchild = spawn(exefilename) works but I am looking for a way to run the exe so that the stdin is read from input file. In cmd, the command is : exefilename < inputfilename. I am looking for an equivalent in spawn.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something like this before . In [Node.js v5.3.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), I didn't see a straightforword answer  . The code below works for me , maybe not a elegant solution , you could take a look:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var cp = require('child_process');
    var cprocess = cp.spawn('exefilename');

    fs.readFile('inputfilename',function (err, data){
        if(err) throw err;

        //redirect standard input from inputfile
        cprocess.stdin.write(data);

        //end of standard input
        cprocess.stdin.end(function(){
            console.log('end of stdin');
        });

        //listen on your cprocess closing 
        cprocess.on('close',function (code){
            console.log('ps process exited with code ' + code);
        });
   });
```